# Camera movement, Draw grid

Tags: 2d, javascript, html-canvas

If I have a 20x10 grid (640x320) where tiles are 32x32

The grid are rendered:

```
for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {

    var tileX = Math.round(Camera.x / 32);
    var tileY = Math.round(Camera.y / 32);

    var tile = Game.map[tileY][tileX];

    rect(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32);

  }
}
```

The camera follows a Player object and is in the middle on the canvas.

Camera position (x) are calculated such as:

```
Player.x - Camera.x + 320 > 640
   Camera.x = Player.x - 320;
```

When the camera moves, it looks kinda solid (since it moves a whole tile). How can I make the movement a bit smoother? (Perhaps showing part of the next tile on either side, rather than the whole at once)

Answer (score 2):

A question similar to this was answered [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132064/2d-tile-movement-and-camera/132393?noredirect=1#comment231126_132393).

But I'll repost my answer here as well.

So I've answered your question by creating this [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/Kitanga/Tile-World). You can [play the game here](https://kitanga.github.io/Tile-World/). Use cursor

**Edit:It had a bug, fixed it. Thank GOD! Added code explanation below**

So the game works like this

- We initialize the game:

  - We set event listeners for controls
  - We load all assets into the game
  - And when all the assets are loaded we start creating the world
- Create the world using the dimensions given & number of tiles specified.
- After the world is created a sprite is created and the game's loop started.
- In the loop:

  - update() and draw() the sprite

    - The update() checks for input and updates sprite `pos.x` and `pos.y` accordingly.
    - The draw() draws the sprite's image onto the player canvas.
  - We then clear the viewport's canvas (This is where the world is drawn. Think of the world as a static background. Anything that moves will have to be drawn on another canvas.) and draw the part of the world canvas that we want.
  - Lastly, we call the loop again.

This is the whole process. Remember that the world canvas is just a background, so any sprite or game element that does't move (e.g. castle walls) should be drawn here (of course adding them as sprite. So that you can, for example, check collisions with the wall).

### How the viewport and character are drawn

We draw the character using two different coordinate objects

- In the first we use the `pos2` object. We use this to draw the character onto the player canvas which is a canvas that tricks the player into thinking that the character is actually in the world and yet he is actually being drawn over the viewport. The player canvas is over the viewport canvas (using css to do that). This object is only used to draw the character not move it around the world. The character is drawn on the center of the player canvas until he reaches near the edge of the world canvas. At this point, we will use the character's world canvas coordinates to draw onto the player canvas.
- The `pos` object holds the character's world coordinates. You can use these for collision checking and movement around the world.

Remember that we don't draw onto the world canvas. This canvas is drawn only once. Drawing of movable sprites (e.g. enemies) should be done either on an enemy canvas, player canvas, or on the viewport canvas (Creating an enemy canvas is the best idea).

### Here's all the code. Use the above explanation to understand it.

```js
/* General stuffs */
var can_vPort = document.getElementById('viewport'),
  /* Viewport canvas */
  can_pCanvas = document.getElementById('player'),
  /* Player canvas */
  grid = {
    'width': 60,
    'height': 60
  },
  /* This is in tiles not in pixels */
  tile = {
    'width': 64,
    'height': 64
  },

  viewPort = {
    'width': 640,
    'height': 640
  },
  /* Create world canvas */
  can_world = createElement('canvas', {
    'width': 3840,
    'height': 3840
  }),
  cursor = { /* Arrow keys */
    'rightPressed': false,
    'leftPressed': false,
    'downPressed': false,
    'upPressed': false
  },
  img = {}, /* This is where all images are saved */
  sprites = {}; /* This is where all sprites are placed */

var ctx_vPort = can_vPort.getContext('2d'),
  /* Viewport canvas context */
  ctx_pCanvas = can_pCanvas.getContext('2d'),
  /* Player canvas context */
  ctx_world = can_world.getContext('2d'); /* World canvas context */

function init(key, assets) {
  /* Begin handling key presses */
  document.onkeydown = keyDownHandler;
  document.onkeyup = keyUpHandler;

  /* Load assets. This is very simple, to save time. */
  for (var i = 0, len = assets.length; i < len; i++) {
    var image = new Image();
    if (i !== len - 1) { /* If this isn't the last iteration */
      var str = key[i];
      image.onload = function() {
        // console.log(str)
        img[str] = this;
      };
    } else { /* Now if this is the last iteration */
      var str2 = key[i];
      image.onload = function() {
        img[str2] = this; /* Add the image as a property to img */
        createWorld(grid.width, grid.height, tile.width, tile.height);
      };
    }
    image.src = assets[i];
  }
}

function createWorld(_numTileWidth, _numTileHeight, _tWidth, _tHeight) {
  /* Following for loop makes the world canvas */
  for (var i = 0, len = _numTileHeight; i < len; i++) {
    for (var k = 0, len2 = _numTileWidth; k < len2; k++) {
      var x = k * _tWidth,
        y = i * _tHeight,
        image = img['tile']; /*getImg('tile') ==> Don't know why this failed, but in the interest of time */
      ctx_world.drawImage(image, x, y, _tWidth, _tHeight);
    }
  }
  /* Here we add the sprite, 'player' */
  addSprite('player');

  /* The game starts here */
  requestAnimationFrame(loop); /* Start the game after world is drawn */
}

function loop() {
  /* Do game stuff here */

  sprites['player'].update(); /* Update player sprite position */
  sprites['player'].draw(); /* Draw player at new/old position. I didn't optimize */

  ctx_vPort.clearRect(0, 0, can_vPort.width, can_vPort.height); /* Clear viewport canvas */
  ctx_vPort.drawImage(can_world, (sprites.player.pos.x < 320 || sprites.player.pos.x > can_world.width - 320) ? 0 : (sprites['player'].pos.x + (sprites['player'].width / 2) - 320), (sprites.player.pos.y < 320 || sprites.player.pos.y > can_world.height - 320) ? 0 : (sprites['player'].pos.y + (sprites['player'].height / 2) - 320), 640, 640, 0, 0, 640, 640); /* This is the 'viewport' itself btw. Just read it ou loud, helps when you want to understand what's going on */
  requestAnimationFrame(loop); /* Loop!!!! */
}

function keyDownHandler(event) { /* Handler for keyup events */
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    cursor.rightPressed = true;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    cursor.leftPressed = true;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    cursor.downPressed = true;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    cursor.upPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(event) { /* Handler for keydown events */
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    cursor.rightPressed = false;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    cursor.leftPressed = false;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    cursor.downPressed = false;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    cursor.upPressed = false;
  }
}

function createElement(ele, attrObj) {
  /* Create the new Element */
  var element = document.createElement(ele);

  /* Do the following only if attrObj exists */
  if (attrObj) {
    /* Loop through attrObj's properties to set the element's attributes */
    for (var i in attrObj) {
      element.setAttribute(i, attrObj[i]);
      /* attrObj's format:
          {
              'attribute name': "Attribute's value"
          }
      */
    }
  }

  /* Return the new element */
  return element;
}

function Sprite(key) {

  /* Position of sprite in world */
  this.pos = {
    'x': can_world.width / 2,
    'y': can_world.height / 2
  };

  this.pos2 = { /* Sprite's position in player canvas */
    'x': can_pCanvas.width / 2,
    'y': can_pCanvas.height / 2
  };

  this.speed = { /* Speed of sprite */
    'x': 5,
    'y': 5
  };

  /* Use a helper function that returns an object with x and y as it's properties for the above */

  /* Image reference for sprite. */
  this.img = img[key]; /* The image for sprite */
  this.width = this.img.width; /* Width of sprite image */
  this.height = this.img.height; /* Height of sprite image */

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx_pCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, can_pCanvas.width, can_pCanvas.height); /* Clear the whole player canvas (a canvas used to draw the character only */
    /* This makes sure that the camera stops when the character is near the edge of the screen */
    if (this.pos.x < 320) {
      this.pos2.x = this.pos.x;
    } else if (this.pos.x > can_world.width - 320) {
      this.pos2.x = 640 - (can_world.width - this.pos.x);
    } else {
      this.pos2.x = can_pCanvas.width / 2;
    }

    if (this.pos.y < 320) {
      this.pos2.y = this.pos.y;
    } else if (this.pos.y > can_world.height - 320) {
      this.pos2.y = 640 - (can_world.height - this.pos.y);
    } else {
      this.pos2.y = can_pCanvas.height / 2;
    }

    ctx_pCanvas.drawImage(this.img, this.pos2.x, this.pos2.y); /* Draw the character using it's secondary position */
    // console.log(this.pos2.x, this.pos2.y)
  };

  this.update = function() {
    /* Here we check to see if any buttons where pressed and if our character is in the world */
    if (cursor.rightPressed && this.pos.x < can_world.width - this.width) {
      this.pos.x += this.speed.x;
    } else if (cursor.leftPressed && this.pos.x >= 0) {
      this.pos.x -= this.speed.x;
    }
    if (cursor.downPressed && this.pos.y < can_world.height - this.height) {
      this.pos.y += this.speed.y;
    } else if (cursor.upPressed && this.pos.y >= 0) {
      this.pos.y -= this.speed.y;
    }
  };
}

function addSprite(key) {
  sprites[key] = new Sprite(key); /* Add the sprite using the key as a reference*/
}

// document.body.appendChild(can_world); Don't uncomment this. Unless you want to see the whole world as it's rendering

/* The magic begins here */
init(['tile', 'player'], ['tile.png', 'player.png']);
```

If you run the game you'll see a black box (32x32px) in a world filled with 64x64px tiles. And yes, it's a grid of 60x60 tiles. The game runs quick (For me at least) and movement is smooth.
[Play it here](https://github.com/Kitanga/Tile-World). Use arrows for controls.

I hope this will be helpful to you, peace!

Check the link in my comment below, some really good ideas