# javascript game camera that follows my player

Tags: javascript, camera, html-canvas, html

I am experimenting with game developement [here](http://billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest/game.html) but my player disapears my player is alowed to just walk of the screen and never be seen again so i was wondering if someone could help me with adding a camera to my game that folows the player and keeps him centered on the screen but allows him to walk to the wall instead of just stopping here is my game code :)

```
<html>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
        </canvas>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    var audio = new Audio('sounds/theServerRoom.mp3');
    audio.play();





    // Create the canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Background image
    var bgReady = false;
    var bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.onload = function() {
        bgReady = true;
    };
    bgImage.src = "images/gamemap.png";

    //computer
    var computerReady = false;
    var computerImage = new Image();
    computerImage.onload = function() {
        computerReady = true;
    };
    computerImage.src = "images/computer1.png";
    //hp box
    var hpBoxReady = false;
    var hpBoxImage = new Image();
    hpBoxImage.onload = function() {
        hpBoxReady = true;
    };
    hpBoxImage.src = "images/hpbox.png";
    // player image
    var playerReady = false;
    var playerImage = new Image();
    playerImage.onload = function() {
        playerReady = true;
    };
    playerImage.src = "images/char.png";

    // enemy image
    var enemyReady = false;
    var enemyImage = new Image();
    enemyImage.onload = function() {
        enemyReady = true;
    };
    enemyImage.src = "images/enemy_idle01.png";

    var computer = {
            wifi: true,
            x: 399,
            y: 200
        }
        // Game objects
    var hpBox = {
        restoreHealth: 34,
        x: 300,
        y: 300
    }
    var player = {
        hackingSkill: 10,
        stamina: 7,
        health: 100,
        sprintSpeed: 400,
        weakSpeed: 150,
        speed: 300 // movement in pixels per second
    };
    var enemy = {
        speed: 250,
        viewDistance: 40
    };
    var enemysCaught = 0;

    // Handle keyboard controls
    var keysDown = {};
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, false);

    addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
    }, false);

    // Reset the game when the player catches a enemy
    var reset = function() {
        player.x = canvas.width / 2;
        player.y = canvas.height / 2;

        // Throw the enemy somewhere on the screen randomly
        enemy.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
        enemy.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
    };



    //w is 87
    //a is 65
    //s is 83
    //d is 68
    // Update game objects
    var update = function(modifier) {
        if (87 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
            player.y -= player.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (83 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
            player.y += player.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (65 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
            player.x -= player.speed * modifier;
        }
        if (68 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
            player.x += player.speed * modifier;
        }

        if (
            player.x <= (0)) {
            player.health -= 1;
            console.log('health decreasing');
        }
    }
    if (
        player.y <= (0)) {

        player.health -= 1;
        console.log('health decreasing');
    };

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        player.x <= (enemy.x + 32) &&
        enemy.x <= (player.x + 32) &&
        player.y <= (enemy.y + 32) &&
        enemy.y <= (player.y + 32)
    ) {
        ++enemysCaught;
        reset();
    }

    // Draw everything
    var render = function() {
        if (bgReady) {
            context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
        }
        if (computerReady) {
            context.drawImage(computerImage, computer.x, computer.y);
        }

        if (hpBoxReady) {
            context.drawImage(hpBoxImage, hpBox.x, hpBox.y);
        }
        if (playerReady) {
            context.drawImage(playerImage, player.x, player.y);
        }

        if (enemyReady) {
            context.drawImage(enemyImage, enemy.x, enemy.y);
        }

        // Score
    };

    function dieEvent() {
        player.health = 100;
    }

    function updateHealth() {
        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        context.fillRect(10, 10, (player.health / 100) * 140, 25);
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.textAlign = "left";
        context.fillText("Health: " + player.health, 30, 32);
    }

    function updateHackerSkill() {
        context.fillStyle = "green";
        context.textAlign = "left";
        context.fillText("hacker skill: " + player.hackerSkill, 30, 32);
        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        context.fillRect(10, 10, (player.hackerSkill / 100) * 1, 45);
        context.stroke();
    }


    function isNearComputer() {
        if (player.y <= (computer.y + enemy.viewDistance + 23) &&
            player.y >= (computer.y - enemy.viewDistance) &&
            player.x <= (computer.x + enemy.viewDistance + 32) &&
            player.x >= (computer.x - enemy.viewDistance)) {
            console.log("near computer");
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.stroke();
            context.fillStyle = "green";
            context.font = "24px Helvetica";
            context.textAlign = "left";
            context.textBaseline = "top";
            context.fillText("Welcome to uOS v1.0 ", 20, 10);
            window.setTimeout(500);
            context.fillText("user$> ", 20, 35);


        }

    }



    function isNearHPBox() {

        if (
            player.y <= (hpBox.y + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
            player.y >= (hpBox.y - enemy.viewDistance - 64) &&
            player.x <= (hpBox.x + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
            player.x >= (hpBox.x - enemy.viewDistance - 64)) {
            console.log("healing!");
            if (player.health <= 100) {
                hpBox.restoreHealth = player.health - 100;
                player.health += hpBox.restoreHealth;
            }

        }

    }

    function moveEnemy() {
        if (
            player.y <= (enemy.y + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
            player.y >= (enemy.y - enemy.viewDistance - 64) &&
            player.x <= (enemy.x + enemy.viewDistance + 64) &&
            player.x >= (enemy.x - enemy.viewDistance - 64)) {
            console.log("seen on enemys Y");
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/theWanderer_Scream.m4a');
            audio.play();
            if (player.x >= (enemy.x)) {
                enemy.x -= enemy.speed;
            }
            if (player.x >= (enemy.x)) {
                enemy.x -= enemy.speed;
            }
        }
    }

    function checkWallCollision() {
        if (player.y <= 0) {
            console.log("y")
            player.y += 64;
        }
        if (player.x <= 0) {
            console.log("x")
            player.x += 64;
        }
        if (enemy.y <= 0) {
            console.log("y")
            enemy.y += 64;
        }
        if (enemy.x <= 0) {
            console.log("x")
            enemy.x += 64;
        }
    }

    //   function updateMouseCoords(){
    //           document.onmousemove = function(e){
    //           cursorX = e.pageX;
    //           cursorY = e.pageY;
    //           context.fillStyle = "green";
    //           context.font = "24px WhiteRabbit";
    //           context.textAlign = "left";
    //           context.textBaseline = "top";
    //           context.fillText("x" + cursorX + "y" + cursorY , 20 ,10);
    //
    //       }
    //   }
    //   function drawViewLine(){
    //       var cursorX;
    //       var cursorY;
    //      context.beginPath();
    //     context.moveTo(player.x,player.y);
    //      context.lineTo(cursorX,cursorY);
    //     context.stroke(); 
    //     console.log("drawing line")
    // }
    function reducedSpeed() {
        player.speed = player.weakSpeed;
    }
    // The main game loop
    var main = function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = now - then;
        update(delta / 1000);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        render();
        updateHealth();
        moveEnemy();


        if (player.health <= 20) {
            reducedSpeed();
        } else {
            player.speed = 300;
        }
        if (player.health <= 0) {
            dieEvent();
        }


        checkWallCollision();
        isNearHPBox();
        isNearComputer();
        //updateMouseCoords();
        //drawViewLine();
        then = now;

        // Request to do this again ASAP
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
    };

    // Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
    var w = window;
    requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

    // Let's play this game!
    var then = Date.now();
    reset();
    main();
</script>
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: WhiteRabbit;
        src: url(http://billischill.ddns.net/fonts/whiterabbit.ttf);
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

could one of you guys please help me :)

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to implement camera scrolling on a canvas is by using  [`context.translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate). It changes the origin-point of the canvas for future draw calls. So when you call `context.translate(100, 200), for example, everything drawn afterwards will be moved 100 pixels to the left and 200 pixels up. So to always keep the player in the center, call

```
context.save();
context.translate(player.x - canvas.width / 2, player.y - canvas.height / 2);

// ...your drawing code...

context.restore();
```

Restore and save are required because otherwise the translations will accumulate.

By the way, you can also do camera zoom with [`context.scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) and camera rotation with [`context.rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate).

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing this ([Camera movement, Draw grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132521/camera-movement-draw-grid/132751#132751)) idea into your game. So the main idea is to only the part that you want to be drawn in relation to the player's position (in my answer linked above I actually turned it into an illusion so as to avoid drawing the player on the much larger background layer).

Now to implement this you would take half the screen from the player's position when clearing the canvas from the main world canvas. Like so:

```
ctx.clearRect(player_position_x - (camera_width/2), player_position_y - (camera_height/2), camera_width, camera_height)
```

This will draw a box around the player and center him/her onto the screen. So you do this each frame the player moves.

Just check the answer mentions above for more info.